# Postfix with virtual users won't send mail to domainname on server

Tags: email, postfix, debian-wheezy, email-server, courier

A debian mailserver with postfix and courier is able to receive and send mail for domains listed in virtual_mailbox_domains without a problem. But if there is a mailadress used that is used during the install of the server as servername.

```
# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, mail.osbournia.com
myhostname = localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = /etc/mailname
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_maildir_extended = yes
virtual_maildir_limit_message = "The user you are trying to reach is over quota."
virtual_overquota_bounce = yes
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Log files  /var/log/mail.log

```
Feb 14 20:56:14 Groudon postfix/pickup[31343]: 7AFA7560F31: uid=1002 from=<jari>
Feb 14 20:56:14 Groudon postfix/cleanup[31442]: 7AFA7560F31: message-id=<20140214195614.7AFA7560F31@localhost>
Feb 14 20:56:14 Groudon postfix/qmgr[31344]: 7AFA7560F31: from=<jari@osbournia.com>, size=296, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 14 20:56:14 Groudon postfix/smtp[31447]: 7AFA7560F31: to=<info@osbournia.com>, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0.01/0.01/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for osbournia.com loops back to myself)
Feb 14 20:56:14 Groudon postfix/cleanup[31442]: 8334E560F32: message-id=<20140214195614.8334E560F32@localhost>
Feb 14 20:56:14 Groudon postfix/qmgr[31344]: 8334E560F32: from=<>, size=1999, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 14 20:56:14 Groudon postfix/bounce[31448]: 7AFA7560F31: sender non-delivery notification: 8334E560F32
Feb 14 20:56:14 Groudon postfix/qmgr[31344]: 7AFA7560F31: removed
Feb 14 20:56:14 Groudon postfix/smtp[31447]: 8334E560F32: to=<jari@osbournia.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for osbournia.com loops back to myself)
Feb 14 20:56:14 Groudon postfix/qmgr[31344]: 8334E560F32: removed
```

What is the causing the error and how can it be solved?

Comment: Could you add output of the postconf -n to the question

Comment: edited post by adding postconf- n

Answer (score 1):

You should check the following steps

1. myhostname should be FQDN, as I see you are using localhost. I would suggest replace with mail.osbournia.com
2. NEVER list a virtual MAILBOX domain name as a mydestination domain!
3. NEVER list a virtual MAILBOX domain name as a virtual ALIAS domain!